# Is there a way to read data from many files, each column of each file to be saved in a separate array

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I read the names and details of each file and then I preview them for a test in `MessageBox`.
Is there a way for *each column* of all files to be recorded in a separate array?

Meteorological charts

```
       var pathFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat");

        List<string> lines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat").SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)).ToList();

        //Display only filenames.
        //foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat"))
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(file);
        //}

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat"))
        {
            // read each line
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file))
            {
                // and show file name and line in a message box
                MessageBox.Show(line, file);
            }
        }
```

I see the data being visualized, but I want to sort them in 11 separate arrays.

PIC (too many .*dat files with the same structure):

[image]

Comment: Are you dealing with CSV files or something?

Comment: *dat files I will upload pic

Comment: For now I see all values on message box, but I need to put every column to be saved in separate array ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want them in separate arrays, rather than using an object to hold all the details of a single row ad then having a single list/array of these objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have to determine what is the *column separator*; it seems it's either *tabulation* or / and *space*:

```
var data = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat")
  .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))    
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {'\t', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .ToList();
```

Now it's time to *pivot* the `data`:

```
var result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, data.Any() ? data[0].Length : 11)
  .Select(column => data
     .Select(line => line[column])
     .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

So you'll have array of `11` arrays (columns):

```
string demo = result[1][3]; // 1st column - (dates), 3d record
```

However, I doubt if you really want to pivot the `data`. I suggest turning each line into a *class*, e.g.

```
var result = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat")
  .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))    
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {'\t', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Select(items => new {
     id = items[0],
     date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1], "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
     /* etc. */
   })
  .ToList();
```

then when you want to work with, say, `date` you can have an array as

```
 var dates = result
   .Select(item => item.date)
   .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** or, if you want to see items (say, `date` and `id`) in a message box (see comment below) all you need is `foreach`:

```
 foreach (var item in result)) {
   MessageBox.Show($"{item.date} and {item.id}");
 }
```

Comment: Can I put in the foreach in my code ? I want to see separate data on message box

Comment: @Ben Johnson: sure, you can iterate over `result` and use `MessageBox.Show` with desired format (with a help of string interpolation)